# Auto generated query not working

Tags: sql-server

I'm testing knowage system, my backend is MSSQL while knowage server is my sql. 
I found on dataset audit log this query:

```
select "ATC_1" AS "ATC_1",  SUM("Importo_Scarto") AS "Importo_Scarto", SUM("Q_Scarto") AS "Q_Scarto"
from (SELECT 
      [ATC_1]
      ,[MESE]
      ,[ANNO]
      ,[Q_Scarto]
      ,[Importo_Scarto]
  FROM [dbo].[MyTable]) T  
  where (("ANNO","MESE") IN ('2017','10'),('2017','11'),('2018','01'),('2018','02'),('2018','03')
  and ("Invio") IN ('3'),('1'),('2') )
  group by "ATC_1"
```

the error I get is this:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','

Comment: SQL Server does not allow row constructors for `IN` clauses. The first could be refactored as an inner join and the second as a simple IN list of values.

Comment: What tool auto-generated this query? You should get a tool that understands the syntax of the database platform you're using.

Comment: The tool is Knowage CE, and is supposed to handle sql-server syntax

Comment: `IN ('3'),('1'),('2')` will not work in sql-server. Change it to `columnName IN ('3','1','2')`

Answer (score 2):

The condition:

```
where ( ("ANNO","MESE") IN ('2017','10'),('2017','11'),
                           ('2018','01'),('2018','02'),('2018','03')
   and  ("Invio") IN ('3'),('1'),('2') 
      )
```

has 2 issues:

- first, it needs parentheses around the `IN` lists (and the ones you have around the two sub-conditions are redundant):

  ```
  where   ("ANNO", "MESE") IN ( ('2017','10'), ('2017','11'),
                                ('2018','01'), ('2018','02'), ('2018','03')
                              )
     and  "Invio" IN ( '3', '1', '2' )
  ```
- second, even if you fix the above, it won't work in SQL Server as this type of syntax (the first sub-condition, that combines `IN` with tuples) has not yet been implemented. You can rewrite in various ways, eg. using a `JOIN` and `VALUES` syntax:

  ```
  from
        ( ...
        ) T  
      join
        ( values ('2017','10'), ('2017','11'), 
                 ('2018','01'), ('2018','02'), ('2018','03') 
        ) as V ("ANNO", "MESE")
      on
        V."ANNO" = T."ANNO" and V."MESE" = T."MESE"
  where  "Invio" IN ( '3', '1', '2' ) 
  ---
  ```
- by the way, the subquery (aliased `T`) is not really needed. It ony adds complexity for those trying to read it:

  ```
  select 
      T."ATC_1",
      SUM(T."Importo_Scarto") as "Importo_Scarto",
      SUM(T."Q_Scarto") as "Q_Scarto"
  from 
        dbo.[MyTable] as T  
      join 
        ( values ('2017','10'), ('2017','11'), 
                 ('2018','01'), ('2018','02'), ('2018','03') 
        ) as V ("ANNO", "MESE")
      on
        V."ANNO" = T."ANNO" and V."MESE" = T."MESE"
  where 
      T."Invio" in ( '3', '1', '2' ) 
  group by
      T."ATC_1" ;
  ```